# safe to use Cpufreq

Tags: hp, cpu, cpufreq

I have a hp pavilion dv5220us with a dual core T2050 (1.6Ghz , 2M L2 Cache , 533mhz Fsb.).    I was womdering if it is safe to use CPU freq.   the applet for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I have been using the cpufreq indicator for a week to change between ondemand wich notebook on AC and conservative on battery with no problem. Check also the guide mentioned by  @brask , it's very useful to improve your battery...you also don't need to upgrade to 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to update to Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit and use the following guide:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 works just fine to me with TLP.

Comment: I know it works fine but the newest stable version always works best and if programmers take their time to update kernel and fix bugs and have better power management it is a good thing to appreciate all this work by having the latest version.

Comment: You can upgrade LTS kernel with the LTS Enablement Stack.